# How to check if a Bitmap is empty (blank) on Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

How can I check if a `Bitmap` object is completely blank, i.e. all its pixels are transparent, without a x-y loop on every pixel?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can check your Bitmap instance (in the example `myBitmap`) against an empty one with:

```
Bitmap emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getConfig());
if (myBitmap.sameAs(emptyBitmap)) {
    // myBitmap is empty/blank
}
```

Comment: @Jeyaseelan Erhm, worked for at least 29 people. Maybe you can give me some details, so I can help you? What you tried, what's your code, where's your bitmap from?

Comment: Yes @lorenzo-s i am sry for negative comment 


i am doing a digital signature where if the user signs i have to take that and convert it as bitmap 

if user dont sign and leave the surface empty at that time the empty canvas is coming in the bitmap i mean white image will come 

if i check your code what you doing is you are creating a bitmap with one bitmap and comparing with same bitmap what happens here is i get white image in empty bitmat and my bitmap also so it fails here for me

Comment: i get this error  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't create mutable bitmap with Config.HARDWARE

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easy but it depends on the application. 
If you have an application that prompts the user for a drawing input, like signature or anything similar, you will usually have an ArrayList of Paths which are drawn to the Canvas of that View. You can do a check when you want to return the BitMap look to see if the ArrayList of Paths is bigger than 0 and return the BitMap if so, or else return null.